# How to flip every character with the character next to it. Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexing

Need help inside the for loop to flip each character with the character before it.

```
function flip(str) {
  //split string


//iterate through split string


//return joined string

var splitt = str.split('');

for(var i = 0; i < splitt.length; i++){
    //flip every character with one before it
 }
}

var output = flip('otatl');
console.log(output); // -> 'total'
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a for loop? (Just curious)

Answer (score 0):

```
function split(str) {
  let splitt = str.split('');
  for (let i=0; i<splitt.length-1; i+=2) {
    const temp = splitt[i];
    splitt[i] = splitt[i+1];
    splitt[i+1] = temp;
  }
  return splitt.join('');
}
```

Comment: You should know better than to write an answer with no explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
function flip(str) {
  //split string
  //iterate through split string
  //return joined string
  let splitt = str.split('');

  for (let i=0; i < splitt.length; i++){
    //flip every character with one before it
    if (i%2 == 1) {
      [splitt[i-1], splitt[i]] = [splitt[i], splitt[i-1]];
    }
  }

  return splitt.join('');
}

let output = flip('otatl');
console.log(output); // -> 'total'
```

You can combine this technique with gillyb's loop pattern to reduce the iterations as follows:

```
function flip(str) {
  //split string
  //iterate through split string
  //return joined string
  let splitt = str.split('');

  for (let i=1; i < splitt.length; i+=2){
    //flip every character with one before it
    [splitt[i-1], splitt[i]] = [splitt[i], splitt[i-1]];
  }

  return splitt.join('');
}

let output = flip('otatl');
console.log(output); // -> 'total'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do something similar with regex and array manipulation

```js
const flip = (stringToFlip) => stringToFlip
  .split(/(.{2})/)           // array of strings of 2 chars
  .map((e) => e.split('')    // convert each string piece to array
    .reverse()               // reverse array 
    .join('')                // convert array piece back to string
  )
  .join('');                 // combine all parts

const result = flip('otatl');
console.log("flip('otatl')");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this cause it's readable, easy to come back and understand it right away

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I am late to the party but you can use reduce().

```js
let input = "vanjskojfdghpja";

let output = input
  .split('')
  .reduce(([o,p],c,i) => i%2?[o+c+p,'']:[o,c],['',''])
  .join('');

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're not restricted to for loops, this is my (slightly too code golf-ish?) answer:

```js
const flip = (str) =>
  str
    .split('')
    .reduce((a, v, i) => (a[i + ((i % 2) * -2 + 1)] = v, a), [])
    .join('');

console.log(flip('otatl'));
console.log(flip('lfpi'));
```